# Error in Connecting with Namenode using HDFS3 library in HDP cluster

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs, pyarrow

I am getting below error while connecting my pyspark code to Hadoop directory.

```
>>> from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem
>>> hdfs = HDFileSystem(host='localhost', port=8020)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Hdfs::InvalidParameter'
      what():  InvalidParameter: SessionConfig: Unknown protection mechanism type: authentication,privacy
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you please add the code to the question above?

Comment: I am using python terminal to text the hdfs3 package.

Comment: @Standin.Wolf..Could you help me ?